# Tridion broker database connectivity issue

Tags: tridion

I'm not quite sure what's going on, but several issues are occurring on our website supported by Tridion 2011 SP1 that I can only think is being caused by the broker db

1, Loading the website results in the error with the Ambient Data Module:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.OnRequestStart(Object sender, EventArgs e) +292
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +79
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +269

2, Audience manager profile synchronisation between the broker and subscription management databases is failing, receiving the following errors from the logs:

Error occurred while fetching a synchronization batch from the presentation system with url: [URL] Profilesync.aspx. Message class java.sql.SQLException No Data Access Object for AudienceManagerProfile java.sql.SQLException: No Data Access Object for AudienceManagerProfile

3, Publishing the website publication repeatedly fails at the transport stage, returning:
    Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_0-10689-66560.Content.zip using HTTPS

I know these sound like several issues happening at once, but my site was running fine up until another web publication was added into blueprinting. Since then we've been getting these errors, and like to think it's all related to an issue with the broker db.

Anyone come across something like this?

UPDATE: Should also add the fact that dynamic linking has stopped working as well, which strengthens my belief there is an issue either connecting to or with the broker database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's full of loaded questions, oh.. boy.. let's take one by one.

> Did you check your license file is valid and did not expire recently.

I would rule the license file out first. If that's not the case then see below.

First, Adding publication blueprinting publication does not have any impact on CDA site. So, I would totally rule this out.

Second, Your site up and running until publication added.. This can't be happening. There should be some configurations changed/added on your web site. Sometimes, the configurations updated but the APPPool did not recycled so you don't see the impact. At later time, when the AppPool restarted/recycled you will notice the errors and might have the impression that the site is breaking all of sudden.

1. Did you double check your configs and dlls?
2. Are you able to connect to your database directly with broker user
   id/password?
3. Any firewall changes happened recently, try connecting to DB from
   CDA Server

Comment: I've been racking my brains about this one for a while, then re-read your answer and realised i haven't already checked the licence file....that was indeed the issue (cd_storage_conf.xml not pointing to the licence file location).

Answer (score 1):

For #3, I had this same problem... is it possible that adding the new publication caused the package size to increase from less than 30mb to more than 30mb?  If so, check IIS Request Filtering >> Edit Feature Settings and look at Maximum allowed content length.  This defaults to 30MB and for us increasing this size to something larger than our package size solved the Transport Failed error (since IIS would just reject our transports due to the size being greater than 30mb).

Answer (score 1):

About issue #1: Could it be you have the Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule configured in the Web.config, but are lacking the java installation? Do you have a cd_ambient_conf.xml in your config folder? And a cd_ambient.jar in the lib?

About issue # 2: you seem to be missing the audience manager DAOs (Data Access Objects). Do you have the following in your cd_storage_conf.xml?

```
<StorageBindings>
  <Bundle src="AudienceManagerDAOBundle.xml"/>
</StorageBindings>
```

About issue # 3: do you have more information in the cd_transport.log or windows event viewer?

I agree with Ram that the added publication couldn't have caused this. It looks like your CD installation was changed somehow. Did you do an upgrade or something?